# can someone help me find a way to extend a list to another list at a specific index?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, data-structures, extend

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
new_filename=[]
new_list=[]
final_file=[]
for element in filenames:
    if element.endswith("p"):
        new_filename.append(element)
```

extracting all filenames that ends with .hpp
for element1 in new_filename:
new_list.append(element1.split("pp")[0])
converting .hpp to .h for the elements in new_filename
for element3 in filenames:
if not element3.endswith("p"):
final_file.append(element3)
extracting the non .hpp filenames
final_file.extend(new_list)
print(final_file)
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
# the output in am getting ['program.c', 'a.out', 'hpp.out', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'math.h']

```
# is there any way to extend the new_list to final_file in the index 1 ?
```

Comment: Can't you just do:

`final_file = [ i.replace('.hpp', '.h') for i in filenames ]`

am i missing something here?

Comment: wow thats so simple thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "extend[ing] the new_list to the final_file"; you can insert a list into another list at a certain insertion point like this:

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = ['x','y','z']

l1[1:1] = l2 # ['a', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'b', 'c']
```